# How to delay a script until the game has fully loaded?

Tags: unity-game-engine

For context, I'm using this script:

```
    void Update()
{
    float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
    if (mouseX != 0 && ready) {
        transform.position += new Vector3(0f,
        mouseY * Time.deltaTime * sensY,
        mouseX  * Time.deltaTime * sensX);
    }

}
```

The script performs as intended except Input.GetAxis updates before the game are fully initiated (a few seconds upon clicking the start button). I'm currently using an IEnumerator script to delay this script but I'm wondering if there's an efficient way of delaying the script, perhaps to be more accurate with the timing.

Comment: If you press the start button, do you transition immediately into the scene? If yes you could create a small loading screen with async operations and to make sure you only go into the scene when its fully loaded.

Comment: Have a central manager type object that has methods to be called when each thing you are worried about has finished when all are true run your post routine

Comment: define `fully loaded` ... simply keep this component `enabled = false` until your game is ready to use, then set it `enabled = true` again

Answer (score 0):

Since you say "before the game is fully initiated" I'm assuming the "start button" you're referring to is in a menu (or intended to be), so you should load the game as a separate scene with a loading screen between.

The simplest implementation of that would just have the start button attached to a function that enables a `Panel` or `Image` in the UI that says loading, and [loads](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html) the actual game scene:

```
public void LoadGame()
{
    loadingMessage.SetActive(true);  //this would be your UI loading screen
    SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene("your scene name");
}
```

If it's all in the same scene for some reason, you can use [additive scene loading](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode.Additive.html) but that's probably overkill and comes with gotchas that may cause new problems.

If you just want to delay this one script until certain other things have loaded and happened in the scene then you need to define exactly what "loaded" means and create a manager or other way for the script to know when it's time to go. So assuming that code you posted is in a script called `PlayerInput`:

```
public void update()
{
    if(thingYoureWaitingFor == true)
    {
        playerGameObject.GetComponent<PlayerInput>().enabled = true;
        this.SetActive(false); //if this script isn't doing anything else
    }
}
```

Note that code isn't elegant or ideal, it's just based on guessing what your situation is. If neither of those work, add some more information to clarify the question.